# model class beans are not being filled

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, tiles2, model-driven

I wrote a web application where there are login.jsp, loginAction and login Beans. When I fill the form in th jsp beans in the loginbeans are being filled through loginAction. When I replicate the logic from these pages to registering an user, beans are not being filled. Here is my code..

```xml
<s:form action="login" method="post">
   <p>      <s:textfield    key="username" label="Username" required="true" /><br> 
   <p>  <s:password     key="password" label="Password" required="true" /><br> 
   <p>    <s:submit         value="SignIn"/> <br>            
</s:form>
```

relative code in struts.xml

```xml
<action name="login" class="com.ActionClasses.LoginAction">
   <result name="success"   type="tiles">welcome    </result>
   <result name="login" type="tiles">login      </result>
   <result name="input" type="tiles">login      </result>
</action>
```

LoginAction.java

```
public class LoginAction  extends ActionSupport implements Action, ModelDriven<LoginBeans>{

LoginBeans loginBeans = new LoginBeans();
.
.
.
    @Override
public LoginBeans getModel() {      
    return loginBeans;
}
```

LoginBeans.java

```
public class LoginBeans {
private String username;
private String password;
//getters and setters
}
```

This is all working fine and beans are being filled. Now take a look at registering a user.

registerOphthalmologist.jsp

```xml
<s:form action="registerOphthalmologist" method="post">     
    <s:hidden       key="role"          label="role"    value="O"       />
    <s:textfield    key="username"      label="Choose UserName" required="true"/>
    <s:password     key="password"      label="Choose Password" required="true"/>

    <s:textfield    key="givenName"     label="Name"    required="true"/>
    <s:textfield    key="surname"       label="Surname" required="true"/>
    <s:textfield    key="age"           label="Age"     required="true"     value=""/>
    <s:select       key="gender"        label="Gender"  
                        list="#{'M':'Male','F':'Female'}" 
                        required="true"/>

    <s:textfield    key="contactNumber"     name="contactNumber"    label="Contact Number"  required="true"/>
    <s:textfield    key="email"             name="email"            label="email"           required="true"/>
    <s:textfield    key="city"              name="city"             label="City"            required="true"/>
    <s:textfield    key="district"          name="district"         label="District"        required="true"/>
    <s:textfield    key="state"             name="state"            label="State"           required="true"/>
    <s:textfield    key="country"           name="country"          label="country"         required="true"/>
    <s:textfield    key="postalCode"        name="postalCode"       label="Postal Code"     required="true"/>

    <s:textfield    key="degree"            label="Qualification"           required="true"/>
    <s:textfield    key="university"        label="University"              required="true"     value=""/>
    <s:textfield    key="hospitalName"      label="Hospital Name"           required="true"/>
    <s:textfield    key="experience"        label="Years of Experience"     required="true"     value=""/>

    <s:checkbox     key="checkMe"       label="Agree to terms & Conditions"/>
        <s:submit       value="Register"    align="center"/>

</s:form>
```

relative code in struts.xml

```xml
<action name="register*" class="com.ActionClasses.RegisterAction">
   <result name="success"   type="tiles">   home        </result>
   <result name="input" type="tiles">   register{1} </result>
   <result name="error" type="tiles">   register{1} </result>
</action>
```

RegisterAction.java

```
public class RegisterAction extends ActionSupport implements Action,ModelDriven<RegisterBeans>
{
RegisterBeans registerBeans = new RegisterBeans();  
.
.
.
    @Override
public RegisterBeans getModel() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return registerBeans;
}
```

RegisterBeans.java

```
public class RegisterBeans extends ActionSupport{

private String username;
private String password;
private char role;
private boolean checkMe;

private String givenName;
private String surname;
private int age;
private char gender;

private String hospitalName;
private String institute;
private String university;
private String degree;
private int experience;
private int research;
private int ophthalmologists;

private String contactNumber;
private String email;
private String city;
private String district;
private String state;
private String country;
private String postalCode;
//getters and setters
}
```

These beans are not being filled. What is the mistake I am doing here? My complete struts.xml file is

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN" "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>
<package name="default" extends="struts-default">

    <result-types>
        <result-type name="tiles" class="org.apache.struts2.views.tiles.TilesResult" />
    </result-types>

    <action name="*Link" method="{1}" class="classes.HomeLinks">
        <result name="home"     type="tiles">home   </result>
        <result name="upload"   type="tiles">upload     </result>
        <result name="register" type="tiles">register   </result>
        <result name="login"    type="tiles">login      </result>
    </action>

    <action name="login" class="com.ActionClasses.LoginAction">
        <result name="success"  type="tiles">welcome    </result>
        <result name="login"    type="tiles">login      </result>
        <result name="input"    type="tiles">login      </result>
    </action>

    <action name="logout" class="com.ActionClasses.LogoutAction">
        <result name="success"  type="tiles">home</result>
    </action>

    <action name="register" class="classes.SpecificRegistrations">
        <result name="Ophthalmologist"  type="tiles">   registerOphthalmologist </result>
        <result name="practitioner"     type="tiles">   registerPractitioner    </result>
        <result name="Researcher"       type="tiles">   registerResearcher      </result>
        <result name="Hospital"         type="tiles">   registerHospital        </result>
        <result name="input"            type="tiles">   register                </result>
    </action>

    <action name="register*" class="com.ActionClasses.RegisterAction">
        <result name="success"  type="tiles">   home        </result>
        <result name="input"    type="tiles">   register{1} </result>
        <result name="error"    type="tiles">   register{1} </result>
    </action>

    <action name="upload" class="com.ActionClasses.UploadAction">
        <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload">
            <param name="maximumSize">3145728</param>
            <param name="allowedTypes">image/png,image/gif,image/jpeg,image/pjpeg, image/jpg</param>
        </interceptor-ref>
        <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"></interceptor-ref>
        <result name="success"  type="tiles">   uploaded    </result>
        <result name="error"    type="tiles">   upload      </result>
    </action>
</package>
</struts>
```

Comment: You have made many mistakes, most of them you didn't post.

Answer (score 1):

**Potential error:**

remove `extends ActionSupport` from your

```
public class RegisterBeans extends ActionSupport{
```

declaration. It will be treated like an Action in some circumstances and that is not what you want.

**Warnings:**

1. Avoid using `key` attribute if you are specifying `label` and `value` too, use `name` instead. According to [the docs](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/textfield.html), it

   > Set the key (name, value, label) for this particular component
2. Always specify a namespace both in struts configuration and `<s:form>` attribute, it is not good to work on the default namespace only.
3. Be careful with the `required="true"` attribute; it works in old Struts versions, but after migrating to a newer release, [it has been changed to `requiredLabel`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25296554/1654265), and since `<s:textfield />` supports Dynamic Attributes, it will be reported on the page exactly like it is (`required="true"`), and then interpreted by browsers like the HTML5 `required="required"` attribute, making all your fields mandatory and without the `*` symbol ahead. I've met that yesterday while migrating an old project, it's really annoying.
4. For the sake of the consistency, an entity representing a single bean should be called `LoginBean` or `RegisterBean` instead of the plural form `LoginBeans` or `RegisterBeans`. Same for instance variables, you should use the plural form only when it is an Array, a Collection, etc...
5. `ActionSupport` is defined as

   ```
   public class ActionSupport implements Action, Validateable, ValidationAware, 
                                     TextProvider, LocaleProvider, Serializable {
   ```

   so extending it and implementing Action interface is redundant.

Comment: Even after removing model driven, beans are not being filled. As the loginBean is being filled I again used ModelDriven in registerBean. Can you tell me problem with ModelDriven?

Comment: Also make your beans `private` and check your interceptor stacks

Comment: @Andrea Ligios. Your suggestions helped me a lot and I have followed all of it. But still beans are not being filled.

Comment: All my beans are private only @Andrea Ligios

Comment: Please post the interceptor stack(s) configured for both actions

Comment: @AleksandrM Why *stop using modeldriven*? Is it deprecated?

Comment: @user130004 : the `register` Action just before the `register*` one doesn't sound like a good idea. Try changing its name to test if this is causing conflicts. Also remember to add `private` in front of your beans declaration

Comment: @RomanC: Nope. Not deprecated, but if someone wants to use it he/she must understand what he/she is doing. Most probably it is better off without it.

Comment: @AndreaLigios I have some other actions like registerResearchcer, registerPractitiner and so on....

Comment: @user130004 I know, I'm just arguing that it may be cause of conflicts to use both `register` and `register*`... you should try to change the name of one of them, as a test. Also consider upvoting (not accepting) the answer if `Your suggestions helped me a lot`, to compensate haters downvoting for no reasons :/

Comment: @AndreaLigios My main problem solved only after stopping the use of _ModelDriven_

Comment: @user130004 Of course, ModelDriven is not a bad practice on its own, but you need to know *exactly* what you are doing when messing with it; that's why me and AleksandrM told you to avoid using it [many times](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25544026/1654265). I've just realized that I've answered 4 of your questions and you've never upvoted any of them, not even the one accepted... is there any reason preventing you to upvote (useful) answers ? It doesn't cost money, it is the free way StackOverflow provides you to reward people speding time to answer your questions...

Comment: @AndreaLigios Initially I don't enough reputation and that is the only reason to not up-voting. Nothing else prevented me. Now I will go back and up-vote your answers for my previous questions.

Comment: @user130004 Thank you, that's gratifying ;)

Comment: I have up-voted 2 of your answers that helped me. Thank you for helping me. I wish I will have your support for my further questions too.

Comment: @user130004 Sure, we're here to help ;)