# Struts2 File Upload doesn't work on Internet-Explorer

Tags: file-upload, struts2, internet-explorer-9

I am having issue with Struts 2 file upload for Word file(.docx, .doc) in Internet Explorer. It works fine in Chrome and Firefox, but I am not sure what I am missing for IE.
I am using IE9. 
I appreciate your advice.

```xml
<action name="saveOrUpdateUser" method="saveOrUpdate"
            class="com.adaptivsol.action.UsersAction">
    <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack">
        <param name="fileUpload.maximumSize">104857600</param>
        <param name="allowedTypes">
                text/plain,                 
                application/word,
                application/msword,
                application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet,
                application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
        </param>
        <param name="allowedExtensions">doc,docx,txt</param>
    </interceptor-ref>
    <result name="success">./pages/login/register.jsp</result>
    <result name="input">./pages/login/register.jsp</result>
    <result name="error">./pages/login/register.jsp</result>
</action>
```

Comment: What is the issue you're having with IE9? Please update the  question with a description of how it is not working. Thanks!

Comment: It is a File Upload function. The file goes through using Fire fox and Chrome. On Internet Explorer the Interceptor  blocks the submit action. I have tried several version of interceptors, even removed it completely, all of them works on Chrome, but no luck on IE9.

Answer (score 0):

Your parameters are wrong, the `fileUpload.` prefix is missing in two of them, they need to be:

```xml
<param name="fileUpload.allowedTypes">
    text/plain,                 
    application/word,
    application/msword,
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet,
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
</param>
<param name="fileUpload.allowedExtensions">doc,docx,txt</param>
```

By the way, set `devMode` to true in struts.xml, and post here the logs where the file upload stop working. We need to see an error, a warning, a message, something to understand what's wrong.

Also in your JSP add [actionerrors, actionmessages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13154159/1654265) and [**fielderrors**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25544389/1654265) printing capabilities, and report here the message you get.

Comment: Thanks for your support. I have changed the <param prefix as your suggestion, it didn't work even in Chrome. I have changed the interceptor name as: <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload">. Again din' work even in Chrome.  I removed Interceptor it works perfect in Chrome, in IE it never hit the server side codes. That's why it never populate any error. Just the page is uploading again.