# Restricting the file type in struts2 using "allowedTypes" parameter

Tags: java, struts2, struts2-interceptors

I have a form where the user is only allowed to upload pdf files.  I use the following struts action to limit the size and file type, but only the size limit works.  Any ideas on what I am missing?  Thanks!

```xml
    <action name="commentAction" class = "gov.mo.dnr.rat.controller.comment.CommentAction">
        <interceptor-ref name="validUserStack">
            <param name="fileUpload.maximumSize">5242880</param>
            <param name="allowedTypes">application/pdf</param>
        </interceptor-ref>
        <result name="success" type="tiles">comment</result>
        <result name="input" type="tiles">comment</result>
    </action>
```

Comment: As maximumSize, allowedTypes is a parameter of the fileUpload interceptor, ten it needs to be prefixed if used inside the stack def: `<param name="fileUpload.allowedTypes">application/pdf</param>`, as [described here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29852474/1654265). Just a typo in the end, so no answer is needed

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem.  The `allowedTypes` should be `fileUpload.allowedTypes`, in this case.